# Repeating a [TestCase] 100 times in NUnit

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, repeat, webtest

I'm converting a webtest that loops 100 times (fires the request and validates the response 100 times) to NUnit.  It seems that the `[Repeat]` attribute only works for `[Test]`, not `[TestCase]` or any other decoration/attribute.  What is the cleanest way to do this?  I want to fire that one test case with those parameters 100 times, and I'd like to do it without adding a `loopCount` parameter to my test case and nesting my act and assert sections in a for loop.

The below code only runs once.

```
[TestCase("arg1", "arg2"), Repeat(100)]
public void testing(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    //Arrange

    //Act
    var response = RequestSender.SendGetRequest();

    //Assert
    AssertStuff(arg1, arg2);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the online [NUnit documentation for Repeat](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=repeat&r=2.5), it would appear that this behaviour is deliberate.

> Notes:
>
> It is not currently possible to use RepeatAttribute on a TestFixture or any other type of test suite. Only single tests may be repeated.
> Since a parameterized test method represents a suite, RepeatAttribute is ignored when it appears on such a method.

With the assumption that `TestCase` is obviously regarded as a parameterized test. The loop looks inevitable, without some additional customization?

What you could do instead is use use a test case source and feed it an enumerable of 100 repeated items:

```cs
private static readonly IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> _oneHundredCases = 
  Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
   .Select(_ => Tuple.Create("arg1", "arg2"));

[TestCaseSource(nameof(_oneHundredCases))]
public void testing(Tuple<string, string> theArgs)
{
    ...
    AssertStuff(theArgs.Item1, theArgs.Item2);
}
```

But for the same price, you may as well vary the arguments a bit?, e.g.

```cs
_oneHundredCases = 
  Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
   .Select(n => Tuple.Create(n.ToString(), $"arg{n}"));
```